Continuous index for dominated convergence theorem
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find $\lim_{t \to \infty}F(t)$ of a function $F(t)$ defined by: $$F(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2x}\cos{x} dx$$ for each $t \in (0,\infty)$. The condition is to use the dominated convergence theorem. The problem here is, doesn't the theorem need a sequence of functions $g_n$ (inside the integral)? In this case, the running index of the sequence would be $t$, but I can't see here which sequence use.

I have thought about using $g_t(x) = e^{-t^2x}\cos x$. The upper bound function seems clear for me, for $x \in (0,\infty)$, the sequence $g_t$ satisfies $|g_t(x)| \leq e^{-t^2x}$, which is of course integrable. With this, can I use the theorem and therefore introduce the limit inside the integral and obtain $\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) = 0$? Is this right?

By the way, I would be grateful if somebody could give me a hint about the derivative $F'(t)$, how to calculate an expression if possible.

the dominating function should not depend on $t$

Could it depend on $x$? I'll edit it

suppose $f_n\to f$ pointwise a.e. and $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$, then $\lim_n\int_I f_n(x)dx =\int_I f(x)dx$

I also have another question. Is there any problem if the index of the sequence is $t$, which doesn't need to be a natural number but any number in $(0,\infty)$? In the usual case of $n$, it is natural, but in my case $t$ not necessarily. Is it ok?

take a look at this for example

To say that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}F(t)=l$$ for some real number $l$ is to say that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F(t_n) = l$$ for every sequence $\{t_n\}$ which goes to $\infty$. So, to go about finding this limit, you want to take an arbitrary sequence $\{t_n\}$ for which $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n=\infty$ and define $g_n(x) = e^{-(t_n)^2x}\cos(x)$. You can then use the Dominated Convergence Theorem on the sequence $g_n$ provided: (a) you can find the a.e. limit of $g_n$ and (b) you can show that the $g_n$'s are dominated by some integrable function.
(Notice that your $t_n$'s are squared for each $g_n$, hence never negative, and that $\{t_n\}$ takes a minimum value, so finding a dominating function is not too bad.)
Once you've got it for $\{t_n\}$ you're done, as the choice of $\{t_n\}$ was arbitrary.
